# What is a good javascript editor for editing custom DSL code?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a nice / customisable editor to put on a web page for editing scripts for a custom DSL.  Ideally with syntax highlighting (and intellisense would be great! )

Anyone know of anything suitable?

Comment: What specific features would an online editor for a custom DSL have to have?

Comment: oh, and reasonably simple....  I'm imagining a "hey, I used X, was pretty simple to use, just did blah and was done" :-)   I'm googling around and theres lots of weird and obscure ones out there, I'm really looking to shortcut having to try lots out.

Answer (score 2):

For syntax highlighting, look at [EditArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea). Intellisense could be written as a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should have a look at codemirror:

http://codemirror.net/

it's "just" an editor-component and you will probably have to put some work into it. but it's easy to enhance and integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/). You have a good description here:
http:// mozillalabs.com/bespin/2010/01/15/bespin-embedded-0-6-released-now-in-two-great-flavors/

It has a full support for being embedded. See the embedding doc :
https:// bespin.mozilla.com/docs/embedding/index.html

You can write a custom syntax highlighting plugin pretty easily if needed.
You can probably fork and adapt one of the built-in syntax highlighters.
The editor itself and its plugins are written in Javascript.

The project is aimed at being a complete web-based & collaborative code editor, so intellisense-like features should make their way in soon if they're no alreay present.

Answer (score 1):

The successor of the Mozilla Skywriter (Bespin) project is ACE: http://ace.ajax.org/